# Dynamic flow in Android application

Tags: android, android-activity, dynamic

I am developing an eCommerce where I am fetching the Products and sub-products from database at run time.
Here the depth of the sub-products is not fix, means that I don't know at build time that a sub-product of clothes e.g. jeans, again have a sub-product or not.

I think to create Activities dynamically but as per Android Documentation we can not done it.
We have to specify Activities in Android Manifest.xml at build time.

Comment: you are free to create fragment at run-time and add-replace-destroy when you want.

Answer (score 2):

As per your Question you want to display Products and sub-producs dynamically in your application. for that you should have to use Listview to display your UI part and use AsyncTask to Load data from your database/server.

ListView Tutorial  :: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

AsyncTask Tutorial :: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to clarify the data structure of the product defined in your application. There should be relationship such as foreign key or other constraints defined on your eCommence backend database.

So, there is no need to create activities at runtime. Instead, try to define a base activity to handle the common product operation and other special activities that extend the base activity to handle the differents between the product and the sub-products.

The logic may like this: 
Load product data in common activity. then the app decide whether to load the sub-porduct via creating special activities according to the data flag/key defined in product data retrived from database, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think expandable list view is best option for that.Because it clearly shows your main product and sub-products to the user.To create and understand expandable list view please see below link :
     http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/